# Reading from and writing to EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

What is the best way to read the text from an EditText into code, and to write some text from code to the EditText?

---

Sorry I have ment not the TextView but the EditText

Hi all

I am a new to android I wish to write automatically from code to EditText and read in code from EditText

What is the best way to do it.

Comment: You can edit your question you know.

Answer (score 2):

Java classes usually expose readable attributes with a `get*` method, and writable attributes with a `set*` method. In the case of a `EditText` these are:

```
getText
```

and

```
setText
```

see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) (they are inherited from `TextView`)

**Note:** Scroll around a bit. You will see that they are defined multiple time. With different parameters. Pick the one you need.

A simple example. Let's assume you have a TextView with the id `myTextField`:

```
EditText myText = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.myTextField);

// Setting the text:
myText.setText( "Hello World!" );

// "Reading" the text (printing it to stdout):
System.out.println( myText.getText() );
```